# Not able to customize message in onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript

On page reload i have to show the message **"File upload in progress, your upload will be lost on reload!"**. I am using the below code for that, but the alert is always **"Changes that you made may not be saved!"** in chrome browser.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return 'File upload in progress, your upload will be lost on reload!';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Comment: You need to set the event's `.returnValue` property with the text instead of returning it. Weird, I know, but that's what the spec says. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the event's `.returnValue` property with the text instead of returning it. Weird, I know, but that's what the spec says. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
   event.returnValue = 'File upload in progress, your upload will be lost on reload!';
}
```

Comment: Even that is not working. check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/AmalaLiza/3kxp83nm/

Comment: Ah, looks like @David R is right. Look at that other answer, and you'll see that most browsers ignore the actual message and just show their own.